# Out of memory error with Matlab's NN toolbox using GPU

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gpu

I'm receiving an out of memory error when training using GPU using Matlab's NN toolbox, and it appears that subdivision is not useful.
I have tried:

```
net2 = train(net1,x,t,'reduction',N);
```

using various reduction values, however I am unsure if it works for GPU side? It may not. Would using the GPU matrix setup directly as matlab talks about be the way to go or other there other options?

Comment: There i snot enough information. What sizes are your matrices? which GPU do you have? How mach RAM do you have?

Comment: Input is 500,000 samples, 45 inputs per sample. GPU is a GTX780ti with 3GB of ram. I face similiar issues with other gpus (Titan Z, 980ti). Ram depends on the computer, 12gb for the 780ti, 32gb for the 980ti, 128gb for the titan z

Comment: It is weird, that sould be enougt memory. Can you post a running exmample with random data?

Comment: I eventually trained several on small random subsets of the data and averaged the resulting outputs from applying an input. I was using a 9000 neuron network so that may have been the issue. I am not entirely sure.